# Decreasing the space between app icons in launcher 3

Tags: java, android, android-layout, launcher

I'm trying to modify the launcher 3 application. I got the source code from this [website](https://github.com/chislon/Launcher3). What I'm doing is when we create app shortcut on home screen it looks like that as in picture below:

[image]

But I want to remove the spacing between the icons and need to place very close to each other. Can anybody give me any clue about this. Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the mWidgthGap and mHeightGap in CellLayout file. mFixedWidthgap and mFixedHeigthGap is the standard gap between icons, you could change that to get the desired gap between icons